# Matlab parfor seems to not be parallel

Tags: multithreading, matlab

I am trying to start 2 endless (ish) loops in one function, and I thought parfor would allow me to do this, but it seems like it only starts one then tries to wait for that to finish to start the next.

Is there I can start a loop (within a separate function and then have my code move on? For example: (this never reaches endlessloop(2))

```
parfor i=1:2
    endlessloop(i)
end
```

Comment: What `version` of Matlab are you using? In older versions, if I recall correctly, one had to manually start the workers (`matlabpool`, now `parpool`) or `parfor` would just fuction like a regular `for` loop.

Comment: I'm in 2015A I haven't seen that but I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: The pool should start automatically in R2015a (possibly unless you altered something in your configuration). Also try relaunching Matlab.

Comment: I haven't altered startup.m and it doesn't fix at relaunch. I'm at a loss on this.

Comment: I don't think we can be of more help without seeing specific code. This example works fine for me in R2015a: `parfor i=1:2;if i==1;while 1;i,end;else;while 1;i,end;end;end`. It alternates between ones and twos (not every other of course).

Comment: Do you have any shared variables in the loop? In that case the for-loop may need to finish before you can access the variable. I am not completely sure how matlab tackle this situation though, since my experience of `parfor` is limited. If you want to run functions asyncronously you may however want to try [parfeval](http://se.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html)